# How can I see the labels of equations in the pdf format?

Tags: showlabels

I would like to see the labels for every equations in pdf format? this is easier to refere later by looking for the labels in pdf format not in text file.

Comment: Check out http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/showlabels/showlabels.pdf or http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showkeys

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Adding `\usepackage{showlabels}` should do.

Comment: @MartinSchröder It's better closed as duplicate. I added an answer about `showlabels` to the other question.